# How to get a parentless QWindow without taskbar entry

Tags: qt, qwidget

I want to have a window that is not in the taskbar, but still handled by the window manager (e.g for nice hide and show animations in cinnamon). If I use Qt::Tool there are no animations.
If I use QDialog or sth else there is a taskbar entry. Can I somehow control this directly?

Comment: What do you mean by "animations" ?

Comment: Do you look for something like `widget.setFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint)` ?

Comment: The frame doesnt matter. Its about the taskbar entry and the animations.

Answer (score 0):

Cinnamon only animates regular windows and dialogs, the animation works fine with `Qt::Tool` windows at least with KDE.

But you can fix that by locating and editing the file `windowManager.js` from cinnamon on your system to add the `Meta.Window.Type.UTILITY` window type (equivalent to `Qt::Tool`) to the animatable window list in the function `WindowManager._shouldAnimate`:

```
if (type == Meta.WindowType.DIALOG || type == Meta.WindowType.MODAL_DIALOG ) {
        return global.settings.get_boolean("desktop-effects-on-dialogs");
}
```

should be changed to:

```
if (type == Meta.WindowType.DIALOG || type == Meta.WindowType.MODAL_DIALOG 
                                   || type == Meta.WindowType.UTILITY ) {
        return global.settings.get_boolean("desktop-effects-on-dialogs");
}
```